# Flutter : checkbox all get checked

Tags: json, flutter, dart, checkbox, dart-html

**(Solved)**

I have problem (already solved) that if I select one of the checkbox, all checkbox will selected too. here's the picture

[image]

**(Not solved)**

Can someone that know how to use checkbox in flutter help me here :

[Flutter : checkbox sent array data to POST json body parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72833129/flutter-checkbox-sent-array-data-to-post-json-body-parameter)

Comment: Lets work on your secondary problem first: you have a single boolean variable. How do you expect to store 4 different checked/unchecked data values in there? It seems you would need at least one boolean variable *per checkbox*.

Comment: Can you post a sample json so that i can create a example for you based on the data.

Comment: Also add the PetHealthModel model.

Comment: @nvoigt

but I called data from API and let's say I used 4 boolean variable, but when health's data give more data then it will not shown?

then what I need is that the boolean length is following the data from API.

any advice?

Comment: @SagarAcharya

I'll add sample from postman in the issue 
and for the model I don't get it :')
sorry still newbie

Comment: The "4" was only an example. Obviously, since you don't know how many models you will get, you will need the exact same numbers of bools. Just one is not enough.

Comment: can you add the PetHealthModel class over here

Comment: @nvoigt so if the model's added, we should add new boolean in hardcode too? sad

Comment: @SagarAcharya finished

Comment: Don't you think "we need an amount of bools, number only known at runtime" is a problem that has been solved? How about using a `List`?

Comment: @nvoigt yeah, I've been thinking of that. and btw, second problem already solved, I already share my answer

Comment: @SagarAcharya can you please check my last update on the threads?

Comment: yes creating a sample example for you.

Comment: Looks good, now you have to craft the body of the POST request from that list.

Comment: I have added a solution for secondary problem

Comment: Hey @DimasSatrya what does this refer to 'pet_healths[0]': '3', //manual. what is the left part and what is the right part.

Comment: @SagarAcharya pet_healths[0] is the left part, and 3 is the right part. by the way, I made a progress, but still can't finish this one main problem. I'll edit my thread

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok from the code i have added a sample example for you, just copy and run the application to know how things are processing.

Solution Summary:

So you will get list of PetHealthModel and in that we can define a bool variable just for that model so that when that model gets rendered on the screen there will be a default value false and all the checkbox with no tick. and then when you click on the checkbox the specifc model isSelected is made true and only that item will be ticked.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Checkbox Example',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  List<PetHealthModel> petHealths = [];
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getDataHealth();
  }

  void getDataHealth() async {
    // final response = await http.get(
    //   Uri.parse("http://localhost:8000/api/v1/pet_health"),
    // );
    // final metadata = PetHealthsMetadata.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.body));
    //This above is the same where you get the data

    // I have created a sample list

    final list = [
      PetHealthModel(id: 1, healthStatus: "Dont't no yet"),
      PetHealthModel(id: 2, healthStatus: "Wash"),
      PetHealthModel(id: 3, healthStatus: "cutting"),
      PetHealthModel(id: 4, healthStatus: "styling"),
      PetHealthModel(id: 4, healthStatus: "coloring"),
    ];
    // you can use your metadata.data i am using the sample list for demo purpose.
    setState(() => petHealths = list);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('heading'),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          petHealths.isNotEmpty
              ? Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: Column(
                    children: petHealths.map((e) {
                      return CheckboxListTile(
                          title: Text(e.healthStatus),
                          value: e.isSelected,
                          onChanged: (bool? value) {
                            setState(() {
                              e.isSelected = value!;
                            });
                          });
                    }).toList(),
                  ),
                )
              : Container(),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class PetHealthModel {
  PetHealthModel({
    required this.id,
    required this.healthStatus,
    this.isSelected = false,
    // This is where you add the is selected item that means the status of every item can be modified.
  });

  final int id;
  final String healthStatus;
  bool isSelected;

  // isSelected will not be in the below method because it is not coming from the api and this is just for ui change.
  factory PetHealthModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => PetHealthModel(
        id: json["id"],
        healthStatus: json["health_status"],
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "id": id,
        "health_status": healthStatus,
      };
}
```

Let me know if it works for you

Comment: it works, but still not finished my main problem :')
thanks

Answer (score 0):

Btw, for my second problem already solved.

this is what I add

```
List<int> customIds=[];

petHealths.isNotEmpty
? Padding(
   padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
   child: Column(
       children: petHealths.map((e) {
          return CheckboxListTile(
              title: Text(e.healthStatus),
              value: customIds.contains(e.id),
              onChanged: (bool? value) {
                  if (value == true) {
                     setState ((){
                        customIds.add(e.id);
                     });
                  } else {
                     setState((){
                        customIds.remove(e.id);
                     });
                  }
               }
           );
        }).toList(),
   ),
)
```

Comment: This solution is fine when you know the checkbox list is of fixed length, but what if the item is dynamic and you cannot predict the size so check my example above which solves this issue.